# Find the magnitude of a vector given some conditions

Tags: vectors

I'm at quite a loss as to how to do this question, would appreciate any help.

The question asks to find $|r(1)|$ if $|r(0)| = 0$ and $(r · r ̇)(t) = 6t^2$ for all t.

I arrived at the answer 0 but apparently the correct answer is 2. Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

If I understand your notation (with respect to calculus and not vector calculus of dot product)

$r.\frac{dr}{dt} = 6t^2$
$$rdr = 6t^2dt$$ by separation of variables.
Integration on both sides

$$\frac{r^2}{2}  = 6\frac{t^3}{3} + C$$

$$r^2(t)  = 4t^3 + C$$
$$r(0) = 0+C => C= 0$$

$$r^{2}(1) = 4\times 1 +0 = 4 => |r(1)| = 2$$

If it is vector let$$ r(t) = r_x(t) + r_y(t)$$

$$\dot r = dr_x(t) + dr_y(t)$$.

Dot product$$= r_xdr_x(t)+r_ydr_y(t) = 6t^2$$

$$r_xdr_x(t)+r_ydr_y(t) = 6t^2$$

$$r^2_x(t) + r^2_y(t) = 4t^3+C$$

$$|r^2_x(t) + r^2_y(t)| = |r|^2 = 4t^3 +C$$

$$|r(0)|^2 = 0 = C = > C=0$$

$$|r(1)|^2 = 4 =>|r(2)| = 2$$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that unless it is explicitly stated that $r$ is 2 dimensional (or some other sort of constraint given), then the dot product interpretation is not fully constrained.

Comment: @DanielV, Yes Sir. I restricted to two dimensions for illustration purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

$(r \cdot \dot{r})(t) = 6t^2$

so 
$$
r(t) \rm{d} r(t) = 6t^2 \rm{d}t.
$$
which means
$$
\frac{1}{2}( r(1)^2 - r(0)^2 )= \int_0^1 r(t) \rm{d} r(t) = \int_0^1 6t^2 \rm{d}t = 2.
$$
so 
$$
\|r(1)\|^2 - \|r(0)\|^2 = 4.
$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got from the first equation involving dot product to a summation and to integral?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(r \cdot r)' = 2r \cdot r' $